# How to place image Placeholder using Image.network() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I want a fade in image with a placeholder. After searching through internet I came across [FadeInImage.memoryNetwork()](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) and it is working fine as I wanted, but now I also need to call a function when the image is loaded successfully from network, thanks to Image.network() for providing [loadingBuilder()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/loadingBuilder.html) function.

But the problem is that I am not able to use both FadeInImage.network() as well as Image.network() simultaneously and I want both the property for my app.

Any suggestions how to put image placeholder using Image.network or other way round how to use loadingBuilder in FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(). Any way round will solve my problem.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
var image = Image.network(//your code);

FadeInImage(
  placeholder: //your placeholder
  image: image.image,
)
```